# custom control for TFS work item type

Tags: tfs-sdk

I will explain my question with an example. Lets consider TFS "Bug" work item type. In the bug work item type there is a "Developer" and "Tester" dropdown. Using the inbuilt rule types we can only assign "VALIDUSER" to each drop down. This displays all the windows user in the drop down. I want to be able to create a custom subteam under "TeamMembers" node and assign members to the sub team. For example as shown in the below snapshot:

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1267041644094323600.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1267041644094323600.png)

The "Developer" drop down should display users from the new "Developer" subteam and not all the VALIDUSER. Similarly "Tester" drop down should display users from the new "Tester" subteam.

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1267042457029195500.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1267042457029195500.png)

I am thinking of creating a custom work item control and then call the TFS API to fetch the custom subteam members.

If anyone has worked on this before or have any better (and simple :)) ideas to achieve the above please suggest.

**Update**
I just created a custom work item control and called TFS API to get the list of members in the custom group. So this is done. But I would still like to know if there is a better way to achieve same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..There is a better way to do the same.. Thanks to Marcel !!

[how-to-assign-a-work-item-to-a-group-and-actually-have-it-show-a-list-of-values](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/marcelv/archive/2009/04/07/how-to-assign-a-work-item-to-a-group-and-actually-have-it-show-a-list-of-values.aspx)